# How can I find the highest value in a django admin queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I would like to find out what the highest value in a specific field is within a queryset, how can I go about this? I have a list of people who are in certain groups and i want to find out basically how many groups are there, I figured running max on the groups column would tell me what the highest number of groups is for that queryset, help?

```
def some_action(modelAdmin, request, queryset ):

     hightest_value = queryset.aggregate(Max('group') # Not working for me

     for x in queryset:
        x.group = highest_value / 2
        x.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you try to sort it:

```
queryset.order_by('group').first()
```

Or get the [latest('group')](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#latest) or [earliest('group')](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#earliest) value.

You may also find usable `reverse()` or `-group` for descending direction, or `[:2]` for multiple values.